# Visual Studio Properties Window glitch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-glitch

When I'm using Visual Studio and I go on the properties window, its really hard to browse for something.
It has this black weird layout which only displays when I'm using dark mode and also gets worse by opening some tabs.
I'm using VS 2015, but this happened to me on VS 2012 that being the reason why I upgraded to VS 2015.
I've tried changing to custom themes to see if it would help but it didn't.

[Image of glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYMKO.png)

Comment: You could experiment with the Environment/General options (e.g. hardware graphics acceleration). Any reason you did not upgrade to a newer version, e.g. VS 2019?

Comment: Il test those and other settings to see if it fixes it. Im not using a newer version because my pc cant handle it and im learning in VS 2012 in school so going to a much newr version would just confuse me rn.

Comment: *my pc cant handle it* - I wasn't aware that newer versions of VS were significantly more resource impactful than earlier ones; you can turn off the features like code lens and intellicode I suppose.. Shame that the school uses such an ancient version because recent versions are a lot more helpful for beginners eg writing `JsonConvert.` when you don't have NewtonSoft installed will produce a suggestion that installs it rather than just a red wiggly line of "don't know what this is"